# Send HTTP Response from azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, httpresponse

Is it possible to send an HTTP Response from an azure function which is not an http trigger (blob trigger or activity client for example)?

Comment: are you trying to send your manual http response or any default one like http trigger response send to blob/activity client trigger ?

Comment: Yes I want to send a response like:  return func.HttpResponse(
             "Hello World!",
             status_code=200
        )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  In a blob trigger there’s no http client requesting a response.  Stepping back, what are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a function that checks if a file named X exists in a blob storage, and if it's not i want to send an http response

Comment: The idea behind is to send an alert if the file does not exists, so that's why I wanted to pass by http messages

Comment: The function that I'm using is an activityTrigger inside a durable functions

Comment: How about hitting a webhook or a service bus topic?