# Post a large file for analysis by an Azure Durable Function

Tags: javascript, post, azure-durable-functions

My Orchestration function will use the fan-out, fan-in pattern to parallelise evaluation of a 70MB file. First I followed the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-create-portal) and got the Hello Sequence function app working.

Here is the code for the template’s Client function `HttpStart`:

```js
const df = require("durable-functions");

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const client = df.getClient(context);
    const instanceId = await client.startNew(req.params.functionName, undefined, req.body);

    context.log(`Started orchestration with ID = '${instanceId}'.`);

    return client.createCheckStatusResponse(context.bindingData.req, instanceId);
};
```

My aim is to adapt this to receive the 70MB file and pass it the Orchestration function.

First step was to include the 70MB file in the POST request. I made *no change* to the `HttpStart` function code.

I expected the same result as before.

Instead the response was a 500 Server Error.

The function log shows "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory".
The log doesn’t show the "Started orchestration…" message. I infer the memory problem ocurred while forming the `req` object.

An issue raised on the Azure forums complains that Msft arbitrarily limits file uploads to 100MB, which suggests my 70MB file *could* be received.

**Question** How can the template be modified to accept the POSTed file and pass it to the Orchestration function?

Comment: It might be a better architecture to use Azure Blob Storage as an upload location. You could have a new endpoint that the client calls to obtain a SAS token for an Azure Storage location, which it then uploads to large file into. It would then call your existing orchestrator function, but just passing a token referencing the uploaded file which is now already in Azure blob, for the orchestrator to work on.

Comment: The POST to a Blob Storage container gets a bare 201 response by default. Durable Functions SDK provides a JSON response with URLs to query status, etc. I need to return this richer response, but the parameters passed to a DF HTTP template (context, request) are not passed to a Blob trigger fn. Does not look like I can replace the bare 201 response. 

Comment: Update: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72449668/send-http-response-from-azure-function) confirms I can’t control the Blob HTTP response. 

I’ll try your suggestion – thanks. 